# Visual C++ for python failed with exit status 1120

Tags: mod-wsgi

I am using python2.7 and trying to host my flask app on windows server. While installing mod_wsgi , the command prompt throws the below mentioned error

error: command 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

I tried reinstalling the visual C++ for python , but the error still persists. Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with a more complete error log. You might even find something helpful by reading the error log more carefully -- The error is not in "Visual C++ for Python failing" but from the VC++ linker.

Also, instead of trying to configure `mod_wsgi` for Windows, you might find it easier to use [wfastcgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi). wfastcgi is maintained by Microsoft.